# Bad value “events” for attribute “rel” on element “link”: The string “events” is not a registered keyword

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following code in my website, but it is giving me an error and I don't have any idea for this, can anyone please suggest me a replacement for this code or help me with this error.

```
<img src=
  "graphics/Logos/OPPD-YP-1209-71562592.png" alt="Logo" width="71" height="51" />
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Your code only includes HTML. The only _error_ this could generate is a bad-request for the image `src` and then, only in your _Network_ console

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the message in the thread title, the error is actually caused by a link element that looks something like

```
<link rel="events" ... />
```

See http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values for a list of valid rel attribute values